# Add items dynamically via Customizer

Tags: theme-customizer

I am working on converting an HTML template into a WP one, so now I am working on its customization capabilities. I've went through an official WP documentation, as well as suggesed articles on Envato. So now I can easily create checkboxes, inputs and other standard controllers (together with sections and settings) via the Customizer.

However, what I need now is to code the ablity to add multiple social links to my page, and this is where I got stuck, because their number can be any, and I need some kind of a button that would create a new controller each time. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a custom field plugin. For your case I would suggest Carbon Fields. It is a free plugin, which helps programmers add multiple custom fields, and is using Wordpress functionality. This free plugin has a complex field, which is a kind of a repeater field, i.e. once defined it can add multiple items, like social links.

https://carbonfields.net/

Comment: I think this is not exactly what I was looking for, because it doesn't seem to enhance the wp customizer.

Comment: @Deka87 Sorry I can not provide any code for a function like that. But if you are willing to use a plugin, have a look at [Kirki](https://aristath.github.io/kirki/). Kirki provides several additional customizer fields and functions (it can even build your css and js for you "on the fly"). I worked with sortable fields in Kirki before and I know that there are also repeater fields. The documentation on that page may not be up to date, but have a look at Kirki´s [Github page](https://github.com/aristath/kirki).

You can also integrate Kirki in a theme as dependance.

Comment: @LWS-Mo, thanks. That's actually what I came up with.